# Excel - Dynamic SUM formula [0,1]

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I trying to make a dynamic Excel formula that sums values in a row when the values in another row are 1 followed by 0. If after the last 0, there is a 1, the sum again until you reach another 1.

[image]

As you can see in the picture, the first value in the F6 must be 323 (202+47+74), then a 1 appears but no 0 below, so the value remains the same (1997). Then another 1 followed by two 0 that makes 9 (4+3+2), and so on.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another alternative,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `F2`

```
=LET(
a,B2:B13,
b,C2:C13,
c,SCAN(0,a,LAMBDA(x,y,x+y)),
d,UNIQUE(c),
IF(a=0,"",INDEX(MMULT(N(TOROW(c)=d),b),XMATCH(c,d))))
```

---

**Notes:** Refer below what each variable does:

• Firstly, we are taking both the ranges i.e. `B2:B13` & `C2:C13` and defining them as `a` & `b` respectively.

---

• Next, we are using `SCAN()` function to return an array, with an initial value of `0` it iterates over each value in the sequence of `a` which adds the current `x` to the accumulated value of `y` from the previous iterations using the `LAMBDA()`. The return is assigned as `c`.

[image]

---

```
SCAN(0,a,LAMBDA(x,y,x+y))
```

---

• Now, we are using `UNIQUE()` function to remove any duplicates from `c`

[image]

---

```
=LET(
a,B2:B13,
b,C2:C13,
c,SCAN(0,a,LAMBDA(x,y,x+y)),
d,UNIQUE(c),
d)
```

---

• Next, we are performing a matrix multiplication using the `MMULT()`.

---

```
N(TOROW(c)=d)
```

---

The above compares each value in the array `c` with each in the array `d` and returns a `BOOLEAN` array of the same size where if its equal then `TRUE` else `FALSE`. Then the `MMULT()` performs the matrix multiplication which results in same numbers of rows and columns as in `b` where it sums the product of each value of `BOOLEAN` with corresponding `b`.

```
MMULT(N(TOROW(c)=d),b)
```

---

[image]

---

• Finally we are using an `IF()` and `INDEX()` wtih `XMATCH()` to return the required output as desired.

[image]

---

==> The `XMATCH()` function is used to find the position of each value of `c` within the array `d` which is used within the `INDEX()` to return the corresponding values of the above matrix multiplication. Lastly wrapping it within the `IF()` function which checks if any value in the array `a` is equal to `0` then it returns empty else it gives the value returned using `INDEX()` & `XMATCH()`.

---

Ofcourse, you don't have to fill down, as it will spill dynamically.

---

Comment: Good use of `MMULT`. I personally would prefer slightly smaller screenshots - at that size they tend to detract a bit from your otherwise very good answer.

Comment: Thank you so much @JosWoolley Sir =) It means a lot. Thanks again, you have no idea, how much it means when those words comes from `Experts` like you. I will try to follow as you have suggested about the screenshots.

Comment: FYI @MayukhBhattacharya I did some performance tests (check my answer) and your solution has the best performance in the three scenarios I tested. Just a comment  `d` in your formula is in ascending order, so you can optimize the search in `XMATCH` using `search_mode` input argument and set it to `2`, so you can have: `XMATCH(c,d,,2)`. Great solution!

Answer (score 3):

This could also be done without helpers/lambda using MMULT:

```
=LET(a, B3:B14,
     b, C3:C14,
     x, SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)+1),
     y, DROP(MMULT(--(TOROW(x)<=x),--VSTACK(a,1)),-1),
IF(a,MMULT(--(TOROW(y)=y),b),""))
```

It first stores ranges `a` and `b` for easy reference in the formula.

Then `x` is a counter of the number of rows of range `a` +1 *****.
`x` is used in `y` to check if x is equal to or greater than other values in the range multiplied by the qty of `1` found in these rows from range `a`*****.

***** *An extra `1` is added to the range `a` in order to simulate a final `1` in the range `a` up to where we want to sum the final values evetually.*

So `y` is a counter that starts at the first found 1 and adds up +1 if value in `a` equals 1 again.
After having calculated this the helper row at the end is no longer needed, since it calculated up to where it should sum. Therefore we remove (drop) the last row from `y` for size compatibility to the range to sum (`b`).

Finally it checks if `a` is `1`. If it does it sums the rows of `b` where the rows in `y` equal the number in that row of `y`.

[image]

Comment: King of `MMULT()` i would say everytime. =)

Comment: MMULT is very powerful. I learned it on here. I think this post of MarkFitzpatrick got me looking into what it does: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68594673/12634230

Comment: Checking that now, right away. Yes its very powerful indeed.

Comment: Interesting application of `MMULT` @P.b, the only comment I have is that second `MMULT` call repeats the same calculation for `0` values within the same group, which is some kind of overhead. I had the same problem with my first approach. Similar with Mayukh's solution, that is why it needs `UNIQUE`. Other than that it is a great solution on how to get the same result without `LAMBDA` helper functions.

Comment: Nice. You could always make a nice condense hybrid `=LET(a,B3:B14,y,SCAN(0,a,LAMBDA(q,r,q+r)),IF(a,MMULT(N(TOROW(y)=y),C3:C14),""))`

Comment: @JvdV nice and short

Comment: @DavidLeal if the range is large it's worth storing the unique values and using that in the calculation. I chose not to for keeping the formula more understandable.

Comment: @DavidLeal actually the second Mmult doesn't refer to 0's it refers to the cumulative counter (results similar like in second screenshot of Mayukh's answer). Just replace the final Mmult with `y` to see what it does.

Comment: when I reviewed it, what I saw that the `MMULT` calculation is repeated, I thought it refers to the row positions where are the zeros in column `B` from your screenshot, i.e. the same cumulative sum within each group. I referred to this portion of the formula: `MMULT(--(TOROW(y)=y),b)`.  The result is repeated for the zero values, so it made me think that this calculation is done multiple times within all the zeros within the same group returning the same value. This is what I meant as overhead calculation, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: It has a function. If the value in `a` is 0 it gives `""` instead of the MMULT. Since `a` is either `1` or `0` I had IF interpret it as boolean

Comment: yes, but `MMULT` doesn't depend on `a` so once it is `TRUE` it returns the calculation of `MMULT`, that is done only once, but the same calculation is carried out for all rows with `0` within the same group. Therefore for the first `1` it calculates three times `323` but it needs only the first one. For a large number of zeros within the same group, it might by significant overhead, but maybe it is not relevant compared to other approaches, something to test for curiosity.

Comment: How about: `=LET(a, B3:B14,     b, C3:C14,     x, SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)+1),     y, DROP(MMULT(--(TOROW(x)<=UNIQUE(x)),--VSTACK(a,1)),-1),m,MMULT(--(TOROW(y)=UNIQUE(y)),b),IFERROR(1/a*INDEX(m,y),""))`

Comment: @P.b for example I tested my solution using `XLOOKUP` (formula 2) and your initial solution for `1000` rows with the worse case scenario `1` on the first row and the rest zeros. My solution took `0ms` and your solution `160ms` on average for example.

Comment: And my comment above?

Comment: @P.b better under this new approach from your comment, around `80ms` for `1000` rows

Comment: @P.b I don't know why but around 7350 rows, I am getting `0` as result for your second solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254005/discussion-between-p-b-and-david-leal).

Answer (score 2):

### Sum Up Groups

[image]

```
=LET(o,B3:B14,v,C3:C14,c,1,n,"",
    r,ROWS(o),rs,SEQUENCE(r),iss,FILTER(rs,o=c,""),
    ies,IF(ROWS(iss)=1,r,VSTACK(DROP(iss-1,1),r)),
MAP(rs,LAMBDA(mr,
    IF(INDEX(o,mr)<>c,n,LET(
        ri,XMATCH(mr,iss),is,INDEX(iss,ri,1),
        ie,INDEX(ies,ri,1),sr,SEQUENCE(ie-is+1,,is),
    SUM(INDEX(v,sr)))))))
```

Comment: quick note, for the following scenario: 1 on the first row and zeros for the rest of them, the formula produces an error. In such case, probably you need to consider it in the definition of `ies`

Comment: @DavidLeal Nice catch, thanks. It is hell to fix an already inferior solution (see the other answers). It looks like a simple fix but it took quite a while since I first encountered a few surprises after going with `If(iss="","",...`. I hope the ideas are sound at least.

Comment: thanks, I guess I found a quick fix, replacing: `VSTACK(DROP(iss-1,1),r))` with `IFERROR(VSTACK(DROP(iss-1,1),r),r)`. I found the error trying to do some performance tests with your solution. I am not sure about your statement about the quality of your solution. Other solutions are shorter, but it doesn't mean they perform better. I have found that solution using `MMULT` reaches some limit around `7500` rows and some performance issues for this worse case scenario. I am checking it with @P.b

Comment: I tested your solution for this worse case scenario: `1` in first row and the rest of the rows `0` and it performs as good as mine solution (*formula 2*) around `20ms` for `7000` rows and it also works for more than `7500` rows, limit I found for P.b solution for example. My hypothesis is that such solutions using `MMULT` perform worse  when within groups there are a large number of zeros, that is why I am testing this scenario.

Comment: For a random scenario generating `0`s and `1`s for for `7000` rows, your solution takes around `1,120ms` which is `8x` time faster than my solution using `XLOOKUP` and P.b solution even for the corrected solution provided in the comment section of his answer.

Comment: @DavidLeal Thanks for the valuable info and the boost of moral.

Answer (score 2):

Here another array solution approach, i.e. it spills the entire result all at once (*formula 1*):

```
=LET(A,A1:A12, B,B1:B12, n,ROWS(A), seq,SEQUENCE(n),
 MAP(seq, LAMBDA(s,IF(INDEX(A,s)=1,LET(end, @FILTER(seq, (seq>s) * (A=1),n+1),
 SUM(FILTER(B, (seq>=s) * (seq<end)))),""))))
```

or you can use this alternative (*formula 2*). The previous formula has a little overhead calculation, because we need to get just the first element of the first `FILTER` call, but we get the entire `FILTER` output. The following formula avoids that.

```
=LET(A,A1:A12, B,B1:B12, n,ROWS(A), seq,SEQUENCE(n), idx,IF(A=1,seq,0),
 MAP(idx, LAMBDA(x, IF(x=0,"", SUM(FILTER(B, (seq>=x) 
  * (seq<XLOOKUP(x+1,idx,idx,n+1,1))))))))
```

Here is the output for *formula 1*:
[image: output]

In *formula 1* it iterates via `MAP` over all index positions of the input (`seq`). On each iteration (`s`) it checks for the given index `s` if the column **A** values (`A`) is equal to `1` via `INDEX`. If that is the case (otherwise it returns an empty string), it finds the index position (`end`) of the next `1` value for index position greater than the current iteration value (`s`) via `FILTER` function. Since we are only interested in the first value (index position of the next `1` value) of the `FILTER` output we use [Implicit intersection operator: @](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34). If the condition doesn't match, then we use the third input argument of `FILTER` to return `n+1`, where `n` is the number of rows of the input data.

Since `end` represents the index position of the next `1` value or the number of rows plus one in case no more `1` value were found, now we can use `FILTER` again to select **B** column values (`B`)
from `s` to `end-1` index positions and sum it.

In *formula 2* it identifies first the index positions where `A` is equal to `1` (`idx`), otherwise returns `0`. By definition non zero values of `idx` are in ascending order. To identify the end of the interval (position of the following `1` value in `A`), it uses `XLOOKUP` with approximate search (`1`-equal or greater) to look for the next element of `x`, i.e. `x+1`. It returns the position of the next `1` value in `A`, otherwise the `n+1`. Therefore the range of the `B` to sum is filtered for the index positions `seq` between `x` and the output of `XLOOKUP`.

### Performance Analysis

Here a summary based on different scenarios to measure the performance of different answers provided to this question. I am considering the following scenarios:

1. **A**: worse case scenario, 1 in the first row and the rest with zeros
2. **B**: Random set for column A, with significant more `0`s than `1`s
3. **C**: Random set for column A, with uniform distribution for `1`s and `0`s.

In all cases I am considering an input of `7000` rows.

To generate a non-uniform `[0,1]`-distribution I use the following:

`=LET(rnd, RANDARRAY(10000,1,1,10,1),IF(rnd=1,1,0))`

I am considering the following solutions:

1. Provided by: @VBasic2008 with the correction indicated in the comment section of his answer.
2. Provided by: @MayukhBhattacharya. This solution uses `MMULT`, but it works for more than `7500` rows.
3. Provided by: @P.b (initial approach, not the approach provided in the comment section, which doesn't provide a correct result). **Worth to notice that this solution stops working around `7500` rows**.
4. Provided by @DavidLeal *formula 2* using `XLOOKUP`. The *formula 1* was inefficient, so it was not considered in the analysis.

Here are the results for **Excel Desktop**:

| Scenario | MayukhBhattacharya | VBasic2008 | DavidLeal | P.b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **A** | `10ms` | `1,070ms` | `10ms` | `7,300ms` |
| **B** | `560ms` | `1,310ms` | `970ms` | `7,710ms` |
| **C** | `2,640ms` | `2,270ms` | `4,780ms` | `7,590ms` |

I would say **the solution provided by @MayukhBhattacharya is the best one in all scenarios tested**, then the solution provided by @VBasic2008, it works pretty well, but it fails for the worse case scenario (**A**) taking significant time.

It brought my attention that running the same test under **Excel for Web** (free version). I don't get the same results. Again MayukhBhattacharya and VBasic2008 are the best solutions, but this time **the solution provided by VBasic2008 performs better**:

| Scenario | MayukhBhattacharya | VBasic2008 | DavidLeal | P.b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | `0ms` | `0ms` | `10ms` | `9,950ms` |
| B | `770ms` | `40ms` | `1,570ms` | `10,080ms` |
| C | `3,640ms` | `850ms` | `9,930ms` | `10,440ms` |

I tested also @JvdV, provided in the comment section of P.b solution, which is at the end a variation of @MayukhBhattacharya approach. @JvdV is more efficient than @P.b solution, but worse than @MayukhBhattacharya solution.

Worth to mention that @MayukhBhattacharya solution can be optimized because the input argument `lookup_array` from `XMATCH` is sorted in ascending order, so we can use a binary search in `XMATCH` using the input argument `search_mode=2`. Which provides an improvement around `9%`. The same optimization applies to @VBasic2008 solution, since it uses `XMATCH` with `lookup_array` in ascending order.

Here is the [link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlZxw2GG3C7IiGbEQTun_yhtjHdR?e=yPWSPS) to the Excel file used for doing the performance analysis. The summary of the result is on the first tab. Be aware the file has the following configuration: *Formulas -> Calculation Options->Manual*, to avoid any specific calculation interfere other results. It uses volatile Excel functions (`RANDARRAY`, `NOW`) so it avoids automatic recalculation.

**It would be interesting to verify the results by others**.

### Conclusion

Using the idea of finding start/end for each group, used by @VBasic2008 and by @DavidLeal. Using `INDEX` performs better than `FILTER`. For example @DavidLeal solution modified to remove `FILTER` as follows has a similar performance as @VBasic2008 solution, *but not better*:

```
= LET(A,A1:A12, B,B1:B12, n,ROWS(A), seq,SEQUENCE(n), idx, 
  IF(A=1,seq,0), MAP(idx, LAMBDA(x, IF(x=0,"",
  LET(xe, XLOOKUP(x+1,idx,idx,n+1,1)-1,SUM(INDEX(B, SEQUENCE(xe-x+1,,x))))))))
```

@VBasic2008 solution has a simple way to find start/end of the intervals, compared to the previous formula, therefore the performance is better.

Solutions using `MMULT` to identify each group, work better when the calculation involves a reduced portion such as in @MayukhBhattacharya solution, compared to @P.b solution. Which is also good to avoid any possible [Excel limits](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3).

**Both approaches are good strategy, taking into account previous considerations**.

Still an **open question**, why some scenarios work better depending on Excel platform (Desktop, Web) used. Probably internally the functions are not implemented in the same way, or different version for the same functions used.

Comment: Worth to read. Thank you very much =)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with a (hidden) extra column. Keep the running total in the hidden column, and display that running total only when the [0, 1] column is 1.

Please note, in future posts provide the data as a table we can copy, not as a screenshot.

Matching the rows in your data, in row 3 in the hidden column (F is the hidden column here):

```
=IF(B3=1, IF(B4 = 1, C3, D4+C3), IF(B4 = 1, C3, C3+D4))
```

Copy that down column F.

In row 3 in the display column (G here):

```
=IF(B3 = 1, F3, "")
```

Of course, copy that down column G.

|  | **A** | **B** | **C** | **G** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** |  |  |  |  |
| **2** |  |  |  |  |
| **3** |  | 1 | 202 | 323 |
| **4** |  | 0 | 47 |  |
| **5** |  | 0 | 74 |  |
| **6** |  | 1 | 1997 | 1997 |
| **7** |  | 1 | 4 | 9 |
| **8** |  | 0 | 3 |  |
| **9** |  | 0 | 2 |  |
| **10** |  | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| **11** |  | 1 | 5 | 5 |
| **12** |  | 1 | 1981 | 1981 |
| **13** |  | 1 | 3 | 11 |
| **14** |  | 0 | 8 |  |

Comment: If you are using a newer version of excel then using ifs might be more efficient and easier to read than nested if statements

Comment: @JoeJam is right. I'm stuck with Excel 2019. I've been wondering if 365 offers dynamic formulas that would make this easier. If so, go that route.

Comment: @JoeJam I've been hoping you'd offer us a more efficient approach. Posting an improved solution is more useful than saying there might be one.

Comment: you have inspired me to write my own answer!

Answer (score 1):

A simpler answer than many others are suggesting is as follows (inspired by @richardcook)
Have a helper column for when there are multiple zeroes in column B:

[image]
The formula for the helper column is `=IF(AND(C4=0,C5=0),D4+F5,D4)` and the formula for the final answer is `=IFS(C4=0,,AND(C4=1,C5=1),D4,AND(C4=1,C5=0),D4+F5)`

What the block of ifs is doing is similar to RichardCook's answer where the formula checks to see if the initial column is 1 or 0 and if the column is 1 checks to see if there are multiple zeroes. If there are multiple zeroes it uses the helper column to find the total.