# Is there an Excel formula that can count the values in a column, depending on the unique values in a different column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, conditional-statements, unique

[image]

In cell C3 I count the number of unique values in column A:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A2:A12,A2:A12)>0,1,0))
```

I would like to know; how many events were a 'first contact'. That means I only want to count one 'yes' per event, not all 'yes' that I have in column B. The correct answer is 4 not 9.

I am not able to connect those two conditions, to only count yes when unique event number.

Is anyone able to help me with a formula for that, please?

Thank you very much!
Tanja

Answer (score 4):

You could use:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=SUM(N(UNIQUE(A2:B12)="yes"))
```

Comment:  this is really nice!

Answer (score 3):

You could try something along the lines:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D4`

```
=ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A12,B2:B12<>"no")))
```

---

Alternative approaches:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E2`

```
=COUNT(--UNIQUE(REPT(A2:A12,B2:B12="yes")))
```

---

• Formula used in cell `F2`

```
=ROWS(UNIQUE(TOCOL(IF(B2:B12="no",NA(),A2:A12),3)))
```

---

• Formula used in cell `G2`

```
=SUM(N(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:B12<>"no",A2:A12,""),A2:A12)>=1))
```

---

Comment: Mayukh, your first approach is what I had in mind. It is larger than JvdV's formula, but it is **faster**. Filtering first reduces the dataset that would the be input for `UNIQUE`. JvdV's solution does `UNIQUE` first, which results in a higher computational effort. I tested both for `100K` random rows and it confirms what I suspect, your solution is almost `3x` faster (`20ms` vs `70ms`).

Comment: Sounds Good Sir. But @JvdV Sir's solution is sleek & short and like it very much **(Sir's solutions are always out of the box)**. Can you teach me how do you test the performance, last time you said, I couldn't make that out. Also `FREQUENCY()` function is slow, posted since not sure about `OP's` version.

Comment: Agreed, @JvdV is an Excel magician. I shared the source file in the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76426929/excel-dynamic-sum-formula-0-1/76428564#76428564), where I have the functions for doing performance tests. Look for the function: `lib.PERF_MSTEST`. I hope it helps if not let me know. Thanks

Comment: another point, but I am not sure about that. `ROWS`, probably reads a property from an excel object internally, rather than calculating the number of rows, so it would performa better than `SUM` for example.

Comment: This was my initial solution in the comments `=ROWS(UNIQUE(MMULT((A2:A12&"|"&B2:B12=TOROW(A2:A12&"|"&B2:B12))*(B2:B12<>"no"),SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A12),,,0))))`. I deleted that posted the one with `ROWS()` 

Comment: I can confirm that `ROWS` is faster than `SUM`, I did some quick test.

Answer (score 0):

Then there is this version:

```
=COUNTIFS(A$2:A$12,@UNIQUE(A$2:A$12),B$2:B$12,"yes")
```

[image]